# Non-Virtual Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

Is non-virtual inheritance possible in Python, or do I have to use composition?

I would like to call methods against an individual instance of the base class for each subclass rather than a single one for all subclasses.

**Update Example:**

- Class A has an list in it.
- Class B and C are sublasses of A
- B and C add things to A's list.
- B and C's items are both in a single list in a single A object.
- I want B and C to have there own A, and hence their own A.list.

Comment: Could you give some pseudo-code to illustrate your point? Your wording is confusing...

Comment: You want to inherit an instance of a class so to speak? What makes it special, and why doesn't a class work? The only way this could be useful is for shared state, and there are many ways to have this. What do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, there is no separate instance of a base class if the base class is inherited multiple times. I don't believe it's possible to achieve what you're asking using inheritance. Composition should work fine though.

P.S. Your question is phrased in a rather cryptic manner (using C++ terminology for a purely Python question), but I think I understood it. If I didn't, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about how python treats classes differently from C++ is what each language does with the class.  In C++, each class stands on it's own as a definition of the "layout of the instances member variables", and also adds some metadata to a table that the C++ runtime will use to determine method resolution order.

Python works in a very different way; the class itself doesn't define the layout of attributes; rather when it's time to make an instance of a class, the runtime takes the *union* of all of the `__slots__` defined in each parent class for that particular instance.

In C++, how you define the classes determines how those classes are assembled, but in python, they're just sort of jumbled all together (but still in a well defined way) so that you can't really tell where one class ends and the next begins at the level of the individual instance, and this is really just a consequence of the way that python objects are just "bags of attributes"

Answer (score 0):

B and C can have their own list instances, but you must explicitly say so in the body of these classes. Consider this example:

```
class A(object):

    collection = [1, 2, 3]

    @classmethod
    def modify(cls):
        cls.collection.append('NICE!')


class B(A):

    collection = A.collection[:]


class C(A):

    collection = A.collection + [4, 5]


print A.collection
# [1, 2, 3]
print B.collection
# [1, 2, 3]
print C.collection
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
B.modify()
C.modify()
print A.collection
# [1, 2, 3]
print B.collection
# [1, 2, 3, 'NICE!']
print C.collection
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'NICE!']
```

Comment: However, if I understand correctly, B and C instances will now always share their collections.

Comment: B and C instances will now always share their collections unless B and C`s `__init__` methods copy the lists.  e.g. `self.collection = self.collection[:]`  Since there's no `collection` attribute on the instance, it's looked up on the class, but the name is then set on the instance.